# Unity UWP (Hololens) get available disk space

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

My Hololens unity application writes files to disk for caching purposes. To be able to check if there is enough space left on disk etc I would like to get the available disk space. How do I achieve this in Unity UWP.

The [Unity Disk Utils](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/simple-disk-utils-59382) package doesn't work on UWP

Answer (score 0):

HoloLens apps are UWP apps, so you can get disk space information the same way as in any UWP app. One way you could do this would be by retrieving the "System.FreeSpace" and "System.Capacity" properties of a folder on a drive it is interested in.

[ApplicationData.TemporaryFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data#temporary-app-data) is a good place for cached files, so that's a good location to check.

Here is a sample function that gets the FreeSpace and Capacity of the drive that the app's ApplicationData is in:

```
const String k_freeSpace = "System.FreeSpace";
const String k_totalSpace = "System.Capacity";
 
#if WINDOWS_UWP && !UNITY_EDITOR

StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;// or LocalFolder, etc.
var props = await folder.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new string[] { k_freeSpace, k_totalSpace });
Debug.WriteLine("FreeSpace: " + (UInt64)props[k_freeSpace]);
Debug.WriteLine("Capacity:  " + (UInt64)props[k_totalSpace]);

#endif
```

Comment: I tried this but the freespace it would give me was in the number of exabytes. But that might be because of the folder being used